# Is a quantum eraser instantaneous?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-eraser

I'm going through the basic and popular optical quantum-eraser experiment with laser and polarizers and I have a question.

[image: quantum eraser experiment]

After applying the diagonally aligned polarizer at a 45 degree angle, the `B1` section of the beam carries an interference that can be observed by the fringes at the screen.

But let say we could, somehow, check the `B0` section of the beam for the existence of interference without disturbing the beam... would there be interference there too?

According to quantum mechanics, once the eraser is applied to the beam, the which-path information is erased and the interference should exist throughout the apparatus, but I'm not sure what the math theory and the experimental experience tells us about a simple quantum eraser.

Answer (score 3):

The interference pattern only appears after the diagonal polarizer. I just performed the experiment with a Michelson interferometer. I place polarizers orthogonal to each other in each path of the interferometer. I also put a beam splitter in section b0. When the diagonal polarizer was position at B1 the interference pattern reappeared, but the beam splitter at B0 continued to project no interference pattern.[image]

Comment: Great experiment, I thought about it previously and the flaw is that, when split, you get two new beams and the beam with no interference never goes through the D polarizer eraser. Imagine you fire single photons. If the photon, at the splitter, takes your new path B3 it never encounters a diagonal polarizer so it retains WP information and hence no interference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty bad example of a quantum eraser experiment, because it can be explained **entirely using classical electromagnetism**. Specifically, the two concepts involved are:

- [*Malus's Law*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Malus's_law_and_other_properties), which describes the output intensity of light as it passes through a linear polarizer, and
- The [*Fresnel-Arago laws*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel%E2%80%93Arago_laws), which, among other things, state that coherent polarized light can only interfere with the component of another coherent light source which is *parallel* to its polarization. In particular, this means that two coherent light beams that are polarized perpendicular to each other cannot interfere.

The $B_0$ section of the beam contains two orthogonally polarized light beams. Therefore, by the Fresnel-Arago laws, no interference can be present.

Comment: But the beams do interfere, only that it occurs after the diagonal polarizer D which is not causing the interference itself. So the slit interference must be present in B0 too, but encoded some other way. How is it encoded into B0 so that it's only revealed after the D polarizer? How or can we detect that B0 conceals that potential interference without modifying (collapsing) the system?

Comment: @ojosilva It's not "encoded" in $B_0$. The D polarizer changes the polarization of both beams, such that both beams have the same polarization after passing though it. By the Fresnel-Arago laws, they can therefore interfere in $B_1$.

Comment: @ojosilva In that sense, it arguably does make sense to say that the D polarizer is causing the interference.

Comment: But in any case, if they do not interfere in B0 (due to being orthogonally polarized) and only after B1, the interference pattern on the screen should be significantly different when polarizers are in place than when no polarizers are used at all due to the fact that the diffraction pattern interference points will only occur in B1. Strikingly the pattern on the screen is the same without polarizers as they are with a quantum erased system meaning that the eraser polarizer is actually restoring the properties of the wave at B0 *backwards* restituting interference.

Comment: @ojosilva The Fresnel-Arago laws also state that two coherent unpolarized light sources interfere in the same way as two coherent light sources that are linearly polarized in the same orientation. So the case when no polarizers are present is explained completely within classical electromagnetism as well.